# could not reach CMS from JBOSS

Tags: jboss, business-objects

I have ran into something interesting. We are upgrading our SAP BO from 4.2 SP2 to 4.2 SP5. So we have a java application which runs on JBoss connects to the BO reports.

So as part of upgrade I have updated all my SAP jars and tried connecting to the new CMS. To test out initially I used the below code and ran it using main method I was able to connect to the  CMS and get the Session.

```
ITrustedPrincipal trustedPrincipal = sessionMgr.createTrustedPrincipal("user1", "myCMS:6400");
session = sessionMgr.logon(trustedPrincipal);
```

But when I run the same code on JBoss, I get

> Could not reach CMS 'myCMS:6400'. Specify the correct host and port
> and check for network issues

Can some one please suggest what I am doing wrong?